# _wgetenv gets ?? mark values when value contains Unicode characters (japanese)

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi

(Title updated to indicate that problem was with _wgetenv)

The following program fails with  [error 123](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when the variable has path that contains japanese text. The same program works fine when compiled with Visual Studio 2005.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int  main  (int argc, char  **argv ) {
        wchar_t *wcharVarName= L"TEMP_PATH";
        wchar_t *longTempPath= _wgetenv(wcharVarName);

        MessageBoxW( NULL,  longTempPath, longTempPath, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

        int wlength = GetShortPathNameW(longTempPath,0,0);
        int error= GetLastError();
        if ( wlength == 0 ) {
                char buf[1000];
                sprintf ( buf, "error code %d",error);
                MessageBox( NULL, "FAIL", buf, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        }
        else {
             MessageBoxW( NULL, longTempPath, wcharVarName, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        }

}
```

Is there way to make above program works with Visual Studio 6?

Edit:
The TEMP_PATH was C:\tmp\漢字. The _wgetenv shows...

[image]

Comment: Can you show what `longTempPath` contains?

Comment: @  David Heffernan : Looks like getenv failed?

Comment: Try calling [`GetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188(v=vs.85).aspx) instead

Comment: @  David Heffernan : that worked. I edited the title to indicate the real problem. Could you 'answer' my question, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, the call to `_wgetenv` is not returning the desired value under VS6. The `?` symbols indicate that an encoding conversion has failed.

A quick workaround is to use [`GetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188.aspx) instead.